# Command "git add <file>" adds ALL files to the stage

Tags: git

There are plenty of git commands where a file name can be specified. They don't seem to work right in my project, because these commands still apply to all files instead of one.

Examples:

```
git add <file> # causes adding all files to the stage, not just one
git checkout <file> # discard all changes
git log -- file # works as usual git log command
git blame <file> # this one seems to work right
```

Do I do something wrong or is something wrong with my git? How can I fix it, especially `git add file` problem?

Detailed example of `git add <file>`:

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   file1
        modified:   file2
        modified:   file3

$ git add file1
$ git status
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

        modified:   file1
        modified:   file2
        modified:   file3
```

Comment: What is the literal command that you are using? `git add path/to/file` should only (and only) this file to the staging area, no other files will be added. How do you check which changes are added to the staging area? `git status` show only this single file as "to be committed"

Comment: you can also use `git reset` to remove unintentionally added files from the staging area...

Comment: @knittl I updated my question with a detailed example of git add <file>

Comment: Could it be that you have problems with line endings in your files? Which OS is this? What does `git diff --cached` show for the changed files? Does this happen all the time or only once (so once committed, it wouldn't happen again?)

Comment: How the line endings can affect this? I suppose we have mix of windows and unix EOL (\r\n and \n). We use AIX OS. `git diff --cached` shows all changes to be committed.

Comment: What are "all changes"? If the changes contain all lines in the files, this hints at problems with line endings. If a single file contains mixed Windows and Unix line endings, this can cause problems depending on configuration. When committing a file, line endings are normalized.

Comment: @knittl "all changes" means all lines in the files. Mostly we have windows-endings and never mixed endings in one file. git doesn't work correctly with windows endings?

Comment: Git works with Windows line endings. But depending on configuration you can encounter weird behavior. Have a look at https://help.github.com/en/github/using-git/configuring-git-to-handle-line-endings if that helps you. Also, check your current configuration of line endings (`git config` and `.gitattributes`)

Comment: @knittl I've read the article and in addition the article in https://adaptivepatchwork.com/2012/03/01/mind-the-end-of-your-line. Now I know how to tune line endings behavior, but... I still can't understand, what should I strive for? I have "core.autocrlf=input" and CRLF endings, so where is a problem?

Comment: @Vikora what happens if you commit your files (preferrably in a new branch)? Are those files always changed again? Or does committing once with corrected line endings help?

Comment: @knittl Sorry, I don't quite understand the questions. I've commited files many times - nothing has happened. And by the way, I see all non modified files with CRLF endinds - is it normal?

Comment: @Vikora So you do `git status`, see changed files? Run `git add changed/file1 path/to/changed/file2 file3 && git commit -m 'Normalizing files'`. Then run `git status` again. Are the files still being shown as changed? Can you do a git diff and run it through `cat -A` or `xxd` to show any control characters that might be different between the index and your working copy

Comment: @knittl No, no, once I make `commit` I don't see these files as changed any more. So everything is normal except that if I did `git add file` and then `git commit`, ALL changed files will be commited.

Comment: No, if you do `git add file` followed by a `git commit` only that file will be commit – unless you have added the other files somehow. This is assuming usage of Git via the command line `git` client.